# Python invalid syntax when using the lambda function

Tags: python, syntax

Can someone explain to me my why this is an invalid syntax? It comes in the line before the last line.

```
import random

class BernoulliArm():

    def __init__(self, p):
         self.p=p

    def draw(self):
        if random.random()>self.p:
            return 0.0
        else:
            return 1.0

means = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9]
n_arms = len(means)
random.shuffle(means)    

arms = map(lambda (mu):BernoulliArm(mu), means)    
arms[0].draw()
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python, `lambda` does not use parentheses around the parameter names:

```
arms = map(lambda mu: BernoulliArm(mu), means)
```